# ImageView xml being returned as TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I declared a ImageView on my layout (XML) but when I try to grab it by the ID I'm getting a TextField!?! Then my code throw a `ClassCastException`.

Here is my layout code (`splash.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/splash" android:layout_marginTop="20pt" android:id="@+id/splashLogo"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name" android:id="@+id/splashTitle" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" android:layout_gravity="center" android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/spacer" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/splashCopyleft" android:textSize="@dimen/version_size" android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/version_spacing" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_version_info" android:layout_gravity="center" android:textColor="@color/version"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Java (Activity) code:

```
// imports

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        // Grab a ClassCastException here
        ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashLogo); 

        // Never get here :'(
        Log.i("GOT", logo.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse shifts resource ids. Try cleaning your project and building it again.

Comment: I would CLOSE eclipse, reopen then clean. Project (top menu) > Clean.
Eclipse gets a bit dodgy with the IDs and I often have to do this.

Comment: @Marcoz In Eclipse's menu choose *Project->Clean...*, then select *Clean all projects* radio-button and click *OK*.

Answer (score 0):

First, **clean** your project and then **build** it.

If the problem persists, **close** Eclipse and **re-open** it.